# js ajax php - post return "responsetext"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can I make this request to PHP and have it print JS?

```
<script>
    function findQuestions(sala, id) {
        return $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "./votos/findQuestions.php",
            data: {
                file: sala,
                id: id
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(output) {
                //return output
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I know that the content is in the "responsetext" tag, but I am not able to extract

```
<script>console.log(findQuestions("<?php echo  $nombreSala?>", item.getAttribute('iddb')))</script>
```

Comment: This makes no sense. You're asking PHP to output JS which you could then run in JS. Just return whatever actual content you need and do whatever you need to do with it inside the `success` handler.

Comment: You're using jQuery AJAX, so the response from PHP will be the `output` parameter of the success handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but they don't answer what i ask

Comment: I don't think you understood what I wrote. _"I know that the content is in the "responsetext" tag"_ is wrong, because you're not using `XMLHttpRequest` directly, you're using jQuery `$.ajax()`. So the response from `findQuestions.php` will be in the `output` variable. You're currently not doing anything with it (I see you tried to alert it). If `output` doesn't contain what you want, then you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: if I understood it, in the `output` I get what I need and I could do my work there.  What I want to know is if a return of output can be done somehow. *I edit the code to make it clearer*

Comment: Return to where? What is the ultimate goal of this operation? To run a Javascript function based on the result? To display the result inside HTML somewhere?

Comment: The intention is that several functions call this and not have to put several ifs inside the success